# Redirect в аякс-ответе

Tags: ajax

Как сделать redirect на страницу из аякс-ответа ? Проблема в том, что аякс просто посылает в ответе страницу, на которую надо сделать редирект, а не делает сам переход.

Comment: а с чего вдруг он должен переход делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
var address = ... // адрес полученный ajax-запросом
document.location.href = address;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Возвращайте ajax-ом,что-то типа:   
   <script>
     document.location='ВАШ УРЛ';
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

можно как написал [@masterMind](/users/8275/mastermind), можно

```
var address = ... // адрес полученный ajax-запросом
window.location = address;
```